# WordPress core Category/Sub-Category Permalink issue?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, permalinks

I'm seeing an issue (or feature?) within WordPress core that I'm wondering about.

My permalink structure is set to /%category%/%postname%/ with category base being empty.

I have a main category called "Main Category" with a slug of "/main-category/".

I have a sub category called "Sub Category" with a slug of "/sub-category/". Main Category is a parent of Sub Category.

The proper URL for this is https://example.com/main-category/sub-category/

However, if I go to https://example.com/sub-category/ directly, I can see the sub category page, even though it's not it's proper URL. It should be a 404, right?

Why is WordPress like this, and what are some solutions to fix this? Is this a feature or a bug?

Overall, I'm looking to have it go to a 404 rather than the sub category show up on the incorrect URL without the parent category in the URL.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you confirm if you are being URL redirected from `/sub-category/` over to `/main-category/sub-category/`?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I'm not being redirected to /main-category/sub-category/ when going to /sub-category/ directly. It's displaying the sub category page as if it's suppose to exist.

Comment: I think this is a feature, not an issue. Consider what happens if you remove the dependency of the child to its parent. The link `/main-category/sub-category/` will be dead. But the permalink `/sub-category` will still be alive.